# How to convert audio send in flutter_webrtc to g711 in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc, flutter-webrtc

I am using flutter_webrtc package for streaming video from a camera. There is a requirement to implement a two way communication in which the user can speak through the mobile and the audio can be played from camera. The camera supports g711 format audio. Is there any way we can convert the audio from mobile app to g711 format in flutter.